# How can I set the frequency of a pandas index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So this is my code basically:

```
df = pd.read_csv('XBT_60.csv', index_col = 'date', parse_dates = True)
df.index.freq = 'H'
```

I load a csv, set the index to the date column and want to set the frequency to 'H'. But this raises this error:

```
ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency H
```

The format of the dates column is: `2017-01-01 00:00:00`

I already tried loading the csv without setting the index column and used pd.to_datetime on the dates column before I set it as index, but still i am unable to set the frequency. How can I solve this?

BTW: my aim is to use the seasonal_decompose() method from statsmodels, so I need the frequency there.

Comment: `pandas` is pretty smart. When you try to manually set the frequency it will in fact first do `pd.infer_freq(df.index)` to make sure you _should_ be doing that. The error is then telling you that pandas does not believe the frequency you are trying to assign is correct because it does not match what it expects, so it prevents you from doing so. For `'H'` to be the frequency, every entry must be **exactly** 1 hour apart, with no missing gaps or duplicate entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't set frequency if you have missing index values:

```
>>> df
            val
2019-09-15    0
2019-09-16    1
2019-09-18    3

>>> df.index.freq = 'D'
...
ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency D
```

To find missing index, use:

```
>>> df = df.resample('D').first()
            val
2019-09-15  0.0
2019-09-16  1.0
2019-09-17  NaN
2019-09-18  3.0

>>> df.index.freq
<Day>
```

To debug, find missing indexes:

```
>>> pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='D').difference(df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-17'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: thanks! that was in fact the answer! I was so sure to have continuous data, since I used the resample method, but i forgot that i merged onto another df that was missing some rows. Your debug line really saved me here :) Thanks again and greetings!

Comment: `resample()` doesn't seem to accept this argument in latest version.  But a helpful answer.

Comment: @RossAttrill. With the latest version of Pandas (1.5.2) it still works. Can you check your index? Are you sure it's a `DateTimeIndex`?

Comment: @Corralien.  Yes - it was my mistake.  It seems to work fine with 1.5.2.